# How to update a child node that contains a specific value in the database

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
String userID = selectedCharacter.getUserID();
String charID = selectedCharacter.getCharID();
Character editedCharacter = new Character(userID, charID, name, hitPoints, armorClass, level, experience, gold);

            databaseRef                     
                    .orderByChild("charID")
                    .equalTo(selectedCharacter.getCharID())
                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            // Translate the character to a map of its data
                            Map<String,Object> updates = editedCharacter.toMap();
                            // Update ONLY the node with charID = editedCharacter.getCharID()
                            databaseRef.updateChildren(updates);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            throw databaseError.toException();
                        }
                    });
```

So I'm trying to update a character's stats in my firebase database. As you can see:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwyQB.jpg)

the code I'm using is actually putting the update in character's root instead. What am I doing wrong here? I'm unsure of how to find the node with the key as I'm not storing the key anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So your code will need to handle the fact that the snapshot is a list. In the case of Android that means that you loop over `snapshot.getChildren()`:

```
databaseRef                     
    .orderByChild("charID")
    .equalTo(selectedCharacter.getCharID())
    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // Translate the character to a map of its data
                Map<String,Object> updates = editedCharacter.toMap();
                // Update ONLY the node with charID = editedCharacter.getCharID()
                child.getRef().updateChildren(updates);
            }
        }
```

Comment: That seems to be the solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `databaseRef.updateChildren(updates);`

Could you try

`databaseRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).setValue(updates)`

Then see if it works.